# Create a dataframe from a file with different delimiters

Tags: r, dataframe, readline

I need to create a table based on different delimiters and keywords. I have the following file:

```
    >>>ENST00000370225_4
    >7E7I_A Chain A, Retinal-specific phospholipid-transporting ATPase ABCA4 
    [Homo sapiens]
     7E7O_A Chain A, Retinal-specific phospholipid-transporting ATPase ABCA4 
    [Homo sapiens]
    Length=2317
    
     Score = 4711 bits (12220),  Expect = 0.0, Method: Compositional matrix adjust.
     Identities = 2273/2273 (100%), Positives = 2273/2273 (100%), Gaps = 0/2273 (0%)
    
    >NP_000341.2 retinal-specific phospholipid-transporting ATPase ABCA4 [Homo 
    sapiens]
     P78363.3 RecName: Full=Retinal-specific phospholipid-transporting ATPase 
    ABCA4; AltName: Full=ATP-binding cassette sub-family A member 
    4; AltName: Full=RIM ABC transporter; Short=RIM proteinv; 
    Short=RmP; AltName: Full=Retinal-specific ATP-binding cassette 
    transporter; AltName: Full=Stargardt disease protein [Homo 
    sapiens]
     7LKP_A Chain A, Retinal-specific phospholipid-transporting ATPase ABCA4 
    [Homo sapiens]
     7M1P_A Chain A, Retinal-specific phospholipid-transporting ATPase ABCA4 
    [Homo sapiens]
     7M1Q_A Chain A, Retinal-specific phospholipid-transporting ATPase ABCA4 
    [Homo sapiens]
     EAW73056.1 ATP-binding cassette, sub-family A (ABC1), member 4, isoform 
    CRA_a [Homo sapiens]
    Length=2273
    
     Score = 4711 bits (12219),  Expect = 0.0, Method: Compositional matrix adjust.
     Identities = 2273/2273 (100%), Positives = 2273/2273 (100%), Gaps = 0/2273 (0%)
    
    >>>ENST00000460514_1
    >CAH10486.1 hypothetical protein [Homo sapiens]
    Length=1065
    
     Score = 301 bits (772),  Expect = 2e-96, Method: Compositional matrix adjust.
     Identities = 146/146 (100%), Positives = 146/146 (100%), Gaps = 0/146 (0%)
    
    >CAA75729.1 ABCR [Homo sapiens]
    Length=2273
    
     Score = 300 bits (769),  Expect = 2e-94, Method: Compositional matrix adjust.
     Identities = 146/146 (100%), Positives = 146/146 (100%), Gaps = 0/146 (0%)
```

And the desired output is:

```
Transcript        Protein                                                                 Length  Score             Identity  Percent
1 ENST00000370225_4 7E7I_A Chain A, Retinal-specific phospholipid-transporting ATPase ABCA4   2317 4711 bits (12220) 2273/2273       100%
2 ENST00000370225_4 NP_000341.2 retinal-specific phospholipid-transporting ATPase ABCA4       2273 4711 bits (12219) 2273/2273       100%
3 ENST00000460514_1 CAH10486.1 hypothetical protein                                           1065 301 bits (772)    146/146         100%
4 ENST00000460514_1 CAA75729.1 ABCR                                                           2273 300 bits (769)    146/146         100%
```

Each desired column is delimited in the original file by keywords like length, identities, scores, ">" and ">>>"
I tried the following script, but I'm missing to add of the transcript (the first column), which is the first column delimited by ">>>".

```
my_txt <- readLines(con = "gene_filt_perc.txt")

transcript <-my_txt[grepl("^\\s*>>>", my_txt)]
lengths <-my_txt[grepl("^\\s*Length", my_txt)]
lengths <- gsub("Length=", "", lengths)
scores <-my_txt[grepl("^\\s*Score", my_txt)]
scores <- gsub(" Score = ", "", scores)
scores <- gsub("\\,  Expect = ..*", "", scores)
identities <-my_txt[grepl("^\\s*Identities", my_txt)]
identities <- gsub(" Identities = ", "", identities)
identities <- gsub("\\, Positives = ..*", "", identities)
protein <-my_txt[grepl("^\\s*>[[:alnum:]]", my_txt)]
   
result <-data.frame("protein"=protein, "identities"=identities, "scores"=scores, "lengths"=lengths)
result
                                                                          protein       identities            scores lengths
1        7E7I_A Chain A, Retinal-specific phospholipid-transporting ATPase ABCA4  2273/2273 (100%) 4711 bits (12220)    2317
2        7LKZ_A Chain A, Retinal-specific phospholipid-transporting ATPase ABCA4   2271/2273 (99%) 4711 bits (12220)    2273
3      NP_000341.2 retinal-specific phospholipid-transporting ATPase ABCA4 [Homo  2273/2273 (100%) 4711 bits (12219)    2273
4                                 BAE06122.2 ABCA4 variant protein [Homo sapiens]  2272/2273 (99%) 4710 bits (12218)    2273
5        7E7Q_A Chain A, Retinal-specific phospholipid-transporting ATPase ABCA4   2271/2273 (99%) 4709 bits (12214)    2317
```

Is there an easier way to construct the data.frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing `gsub` on all data will destroy the hierarchical nesting. Keep your data together. Start with one big string stored in `data.txt` and split them to get one element per transcript. Fields can be extracted using relative expressions. Lists can be converted into multiple rows in a table using `unnest`. This automatically repeats transcript IDs for each corresponding protein.

```
library(tidyverse)

read_file("data.txt") %>%
  str_split(">>>") %>%
  simplify() %>%
  discard(~ .x == "") %>%
  # parse all transcripts
  map(function(Transcript) {
    list(
      Transcript = Transcript %>% str_extract("ENST.*"),
      Protein = {
        Transcript %>%
        str_split(">") %>%
        simplify() %>%
        discard(~ .x %>% str_detect("^ENST"))
      }
    )
  }) %>%
  enframe() %>%
  select(value) %>%
  unnest_wider(value) %>%
  unnest(Protein) %>%
  mutate(
    # parse all proteins
    Protein = Protein %>% map(function(Protein) {
      list(
        # first line
        Protein = Protein %>% str_split("\n") %>% simplify() %>% first() %>% str_trim(),
        # numbers after pattern 'Length='
        Length = Protein %>% str_extract("(?<=Length=)[0-9 ]+") %>% as.numeric(),
        # numbers after pattern 'Score = '
        Score = Protein %>% str_extract("(?<=Score = )[0-9 ]+") %>% as.numeric()
      )
    })
  ) %>%
  unnest_wider(Protein)

#>  Transcript        Protein                                                                   Length Score
#>  <chr>             <chr>                                                                      <dbl> <dbl>
#>1 ENST00000370225_4 7E7I_A Chain A, Retinal-specific phospholipid-transporting ATPase ABCA4     2317  4711
#>2 ENST00000370225_4 NP_000341.2 retinal-specific phospholipid-transporting ATPase ABCA4 [Homo   2273  4711
#>3 ENST00000460514_1 CAH10486.1 hypothetical protein [Homo sapiens]                              1065   301
#>4 ENST00000460514_1 CAA75729.1 ABCR [Homo sapiens]                                              2273   300
```

Comment: Thanks, it works pretty well. Is there a way to obtain the percentages inside the first parentheses of the "Identities" line? The only way I found was by obtaining the whole line with `Identities = Protein %>% str_extract("(?<=Identities = ).*")` and then "cleaning the output using `gsub` and `readr::parse_number`

Comment: Extract the line first and then use a positive look ahead to grab the percentage: `Identities = Protein %>% str_extract("Identities.*") %>% str_extract("[0-9.]+(?=%)") %>% as.numeric()` The dot in `[0-9.]` is for a potential decimal point.